# Html: How to hide a heading when i select a "tab"

Tags: html, tabs

**Hi all,**

**My webpage consists of 3 tabs. When i click on the third tab, the heading must be in a hidden state. How do i achieve this.**

My heading div is as follows

```
<div id= headingid>
<h1 class="heading">
 E-Z Search: List Search Topics & Criteria</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Impossible without seeing any code.

Comment: Add some code snippet about heading u are wishing to hide

Comment: I have added the code. Plz check it out

Comment: You need to provide comprehensive code, at least that of tabs for better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/), you can write sometihng like this

```
$('#headingid').click(function(){
$('.heading').hide();
});
```

Comment: it would be good to hint which JS library you are using in the answer.

Comment: @Anand - very true.. nowadays.. ** javascript implies Jquery :) **  ..
This is in JQuery .. I'll edit it to add that

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it like this:

```
$('.heading').hide();
```

You need to provide complete html markup including that of tabs for better answers.

If your click is triggered on the `div` with id `headingid`, your code should be:

```
$('#headingid').click(function(){
  $('.heading', $(this)).hide();
});
```